# title page in book

Tags: books, book-design, front-matter

I'd like to make a book with front page this one 
[image]

which I found [here](http://tug.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf). For this specific front page the author gives the following code

```
\newcommand*{\cdiam}{\prec\kern-2pt\succ}
\newcommand*{\titleZD}{\begingroup% Zuleika Dobson
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\centering
\begin{picture}(240,0)
\multiput(0,0)(24,0){10}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}
\multiput(-5,-21)(0,-24){15}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}
\multiput(0,-360)(24,0){10}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}
\multiput(235,-21)(0,-24){15}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}
\put(0,0){%
\begin{minipage}[t]{240pt}
\centering
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
{\Huge Selected Conundrums}\\
{\large\itshape --- puzzles for the mind ---}%
\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\large WITH ILLUSTRATIONS BY} \\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\large THE AUTHOR } \\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\LARGE T. H. E. AUTHOR} \par
\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
$\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam$\par
\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
{\Large THE PUBLISHER}\\
{\Large\scshape year}\par
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\end{minipage}}
\end{picture}
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}
```

but I have a problem since I can't make it compile properly. What else I have to add in my preample?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have managed to make it look like this 
[image]

following js bibra's answer.

Comment: Did you add all the commands on page 45-46 in the preamble?

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου  - please see the answer below and let me know if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please let me know if this meets the requirement -- deficiencies may be in your available fonts  -- dont worry if there are errors -- we will work it out --try it and let me know

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage, changepage, graphicx}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=2cm}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy% Plain page style = fancy page style
\makeatother

\providecommand*{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand*{\cdiam}{\prec\kern-2pt\succ}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont  
    \vspace*{4.5\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(600, 0)
      \multiput(0, 110)(20, 0){20}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Top Line
      \multiput(-5, 90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Left Line
      \multiput(0,-630)(20, 0){20}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Bottom Line
      \multiput(400,90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Right Line
\end{picture}

\centering
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
{\Huge Selected Conundrums} \\[4em]
{\large\itshape --- puzzles for the mind ---}%
\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\large WITH ILLUSTRATIONS BY} \\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\large THE AUTHOR } \\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\LARGE T. H. E. AUTHOR} \par
\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
$\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
$\cdiam$\par
\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
{\Large THE PUBLISHER}\\
{\Large\scshape year}\par
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}    

  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT to overcome font problem**
User @ChaokangTai has given a solution to the page build up above -- however the fonts not being installed give the figure `4` in the page borders after compiling

**1.** Download the script `getnonfreefonts` from `tug.org`  -- the link to the font script is -->  http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts

**2.** Fire up the terminal (for Mac OS) and go to the downloads folder by typing into the terminal --  `cd Downloads`

*check the spelling and spaces in the command line before execution*

**3.** Run the installation:

```
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
```

**4.** The program is now installed and ready to download and install all the fonts automatically : simply run::

```
getnonfreefonts --sys -a
```

**5.** It seems complicated -- just follow step by step -- the fonts are now installed and you can compile the MWE Code for correct output of the title page.

**EDIT2**
Font not available on Overleaf to meet the requirement of creating this title page -- reply from Overleaf side is appended below as an image

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!! I'm using overleaf so could you repeat the steps I have to follow in order to get the right pictuer insted of 44444 ?? Thanks again! (When I compile the code you wrote I stil get 4444444)

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου there is no guaranty for overleaf unfortunately since these are proprietary fonts may not be available -- since you are on a desktop/laptop you can check the efficacy of the code and its output on any tex editor -- the question placed by you does not give specific requirement of overleaf -- therefore keeping the true spirit of this site and the time and effort spent it would be courteous to release the bountied points to the bounty hunter--regards

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου -- I got in touch with overleaf and they confirm font not available --reply is attached to the answer above-- hope this will satisfy and prove to be a canonical answer -- regards

Comment: @jsbibra Your email id is exposed in the photo. Edit it to avoid privacy headaches, etc.

Comment: @TejasShetty --thanks its not a problem my personal email anyone can pm me-- no issues -- thanks anyway +1

Answer (score 6):

I haven't managed to solve it entirely, but I made some progress if that helps.

You need to add the preambles that are listed on pages 45 and 46 *but* there are some errors in those. `\defincolor` needs to be `\definecolor` and in 
`\newcommand*{\wb}[1]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}` the `[1]` needs to be `[2]`. So that gives:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\ifpdf
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\fi
%% check if using xelatex rather than pdflatex
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{hyperref}
%% drawing package
\usepackage{tikz}
%% for dingbats
\usepackage{pifont}

\providecommand{\HUGE}{\Huge}% if not using memoir
\newlength{\drop}% for my convenience
%% specify the Webomints family
\newcommand*{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
%% select a (FontSite) font by its font family ID
\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
%% if you don't have the FontSite fonts either \renewcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{}
%% or use your own choice of family.
%% select a (TeX Font) font by its font family ID
\newcommand*{\TXfont}[1]{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
%% Generic publisher's logo
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}
%% Some shades
\definecolor{Dark}{gray}{0.2}
\definecolor{MedDark}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{Medium}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{Light}{gray}{0.8}

%%%% Additional font series macros
\makeatletter
%%%% light series
%% e.g., kernel doc, section s: line 12 or thereabouts
\DeclareRobustCommand\ltseries
{\not@math@alphabet\ltseries\relax
    \fontseries\ltdefault\selectfont}
%% e.g., kernel doc, section t: line 32 or thereabouts
\newcommand{\ltdefault}{l}
%% e.g., kernel doc, section v: line 19 or thereabouts
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}

% heavy(bold) series
\DeclareRobustCommand\hbseries
{\not@math@alphabet\hbseries\relax
    \fontseries\hbdefault\selectfont}
\newcommand{\hbdefault}{hb}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthb}{\hbseries}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\cdiam}{\prec\kern-2pt\succ}
\newcommand*{\titleZD}{\begingroup% Zuleika Dobson
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(240,0)
    \multiput(0,0)(24,0){10}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}
    \multiput(-5,-21)(0,-24){15}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}
    \multiput(0,-360)(24,0){10}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}
    \multiput(235,-21)(0,-24){15}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}
    \put(0,0){\begin{minipage}[t]{240pt}
        \centering
        \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        {\Huge Selected Conundrums}\\
        {\large\itshape --- puzzles for the mind ---} \\[0.5\baselineskip]
        {\large WITH ILLUSTRATIONS BY} \\[0.5\baselineskip]
        {\large THE AUTHOR } \\[0.5\baselineskip]
        {\LARGE T. H. E. AUTHOR} \par
        \vspace*{5\baselineskip}
        $\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
        $\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
        $\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
        $\cdiam\cdiam\cdiam$\\[0.25\baselineskip]
        $\cdiam$\par
        \vspace*{5\baselineskip}
        {\Large THE PUBLISHER}\\
        {\Large\scshape year}\par
        \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{picture}
    \vfill
    \null
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \titleZD
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

So now it compiles for me, except that I still get an error that some font shapes are missing and that results in the diamonds being replaced by 4's. Hope someone else can use this to fix it further.
[image]